# With regex how would I delete all the same elements except the first element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I delete all the <Document> elements except the first one ?
With a regular expression it would be suitable but don't know how to do that

```
\<?xml version="1.0"?\>
\<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_1\</name\>
\<Placemark\>   
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_1\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.701582,29.043733,0 -13.702719,29.043939,0 -13.704522,29.043846,0 -13.704886,29.043939,0 -13.705208,29.043733,0 -13.705723,29.043827,0 -13.705852,29.04362,0 -13.706088,29.043789,0 -13.70656,29.043489,0 -13.707612,29.043902,0 -13.708019,29.043827,0 -13.708534,29.044296,0 -13.709564,29.044221,0 -13.710144,29.04469,0 -13.71141,29.045177,0 -13.712161,29.04514,0 -13.712611,29.045515,0 -13.713255,29.045177,0 -13.714392,29.044877,0 -13.714457,29.044446,0 -13.715315,29.044033,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_2\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_2\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.715379,29.043996,0 -13.716795,29.044465,0 -13.718061,29.044202,0 -13.718662,29.043902,0 -13.718619,29.043433,0 -13.71922,29.04347,0 -13.719907,29.043001,0 -13.7204,29.042213,0
\</coordinates\>
\</LineString\>
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_3\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_3\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.7204,29.042138,0 -13.720615,29.041407,0 -13.721237,29.041144,0 -13.721838,29.041275,0 -13.722396,29.040994,0 -13.723104,29.041613,0 -13.725228,29.042945,0 -13.727052,29.043977,0 -13.729327,29.044521,0 -13.731387,29.044352,0 -13.732653,29.043414,0 -13.733554,29.04197,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_4\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_4\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.733683,29.041913,0 -13.734305,29.041763,0 -13.734434,29.042026,0 -13.73394,29.043076,0 -13.733554,29.044202,0 -13.733447,29.045252,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>
\</Document\>
\</kml\>
```

I tried with posite lookahead but didnt work :

`let test = myxml.replace((/(?!^)<Document>/g, '')); console.log(test);`

Any idea ?

Comment: Use [a DOM parser instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then just eliminate the elements you don't want.

Comment: @Andy yes but I need to keep the first one and remove all the others, and I cant differenciate them between each other

Comment: Is the original source as shown above ??

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes but not formatted, here is the one https://codesandbox.io/s/js-playground-forked-8kbklk?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Why are there multiple `Document` elements but only a single closing one?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius because I merged various kml files, I want to make them into one

Comment: It's not clear how you `merged` the various KML files but more time and care on that perhaps to at least make a valid piece of xml?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius that's what Im trying to do, a valid xml, for that I just need to remove all the Document elements except the first one

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius It is just not indented, and the \ before were put by stackoverflow I guess for jumping lines

Comment: But why didn't you ensure you were creating valid XML when you were merging the files, is what the Professor is asking?

Comment: @Andy Actually, it was a valid XML, though not valid for the google earth format to trace the geographic path on the map, to be valid for google earth I need to achieve the format I'm trying to make, without the doc elements, keeping the first one

Comment: The question only tags Javascript so are you using Javascript to read all the source KML files and then processing the results to build your new merged KML file or a server-side language at any stage to read and process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your xml format is valid. I try to delete all  beside the first.

```js
var documentCount = 0;
var str = `\<?xml version="1.0"?\>
\<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_1\</name\>
\<Placemark\>   
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_1\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.701582,29.043733,0 -13.702719,29.043939,0 -13.704522,29.043846,0 -13.704886,29.043939,0 -13.705208,29.043733,0 -13.705723,29.043827,0 -13.705852,29.04362,0 -13.706088,29.043789,0 -13.70656,29.043489,0 -13.707612,29.043902,0 -13.708019,29.043827,0 -13.708534,29.044296,0 -13.709564,29.044221,0 -13.710144,29.04469,0 -13.71141,29.045177,0 -13.712161,29.04514,0 -13.712611,29.045515,0 -13.713255,29.045177,0 -13.714392,29.044877,0 -13.714457,29.044446,0 -13.715315,29.044033,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_2\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_2\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.715379,29.043996,0 -13.716795,29.044465,0 -13.718061,29.044202,0 -13.718662,29.043902,0 -13.718619,29.043433,0 -13.71922,29.04347,0 -13.719907,29.043001,0 -13.7204,29.042213,0
\</coordinates\>
\</LineString\>
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_3\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_3\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.7204,29.042138,0 -13.720615,29.041407,0 -13.721237,29.041144,0 -13.721838,29.041275,0 -13.722396,29.040994,0 -13.723104,29.041613,0 -13.725228,29.042945,0 -13.727052,29.043977,0 -13.729327,29.044521,0 -13.731387,29.044352,0 -13.732653,29.043414,0 -13.733554,29.04197,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>  
\<Document\>        
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_4\</name\>         
\<Placemark\>           
\<name\>Traverse path TRV_1_PATH_4\</name\>             
\<LineString\>              
\<coordinates\>                     
\-13.733683,29.041913,0 -13.734305,29.041763,0 -13.734434,29.042026,0 -13.73394,29.043076,0 -13.733554,29.044202,0 -13.733447,29.045252,0
\</coordinates\>                    
\</LineString\>                 
\</Placemark\>
\</Document\>
\</kml\>`.replace(/<Document>/g, ()=>{
return documentCount++===0? '<Document>':''
})
console.log(str);
```